# html/css how to put border on thead tr

Tags: html, css

I want to put a border on the bottom of `tr` of `thead`.

I have table like below. I was able to put border on bottom of `th`s. However, this is short of what I wanted, because where two borders across each other is still not black as shown in the image below.

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
table thead tr th {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
}

table th,
table td {
  border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        #
      </th>
      <th>
        Date
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        TUB1234
      </td>
      <td>
        2018/02/22
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[image]

Comment: Please post enough code to reproduce your screenshot. See here: [MCVE]

Comment: @Turnip I've edited the question. Thats all u need to reproduce.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a working example:
(Note that I corrected the multiple `tr`s, I suppose it was a mistake.)
I used rgba colors for the borders of `th` and `td`.

```css
table{
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
table thead tr th{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
}
table th, table td {
    border-left: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    border-right: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
table th, table td{ /* Added padding for better layout after collapsing */
    padding: 4px 8px;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
               #
            </th>
            <th>
               Date
            </th>
        </tr> 
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                TUB1234
            </td>
            <td>
                2018/02/22
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is another snippet.
I don't know if there a way to change it, but it displays which borders are above the others, using your example:

```css
table{
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
table th, table td { /* Multicolored border */
    border: 1px solid;
    border-color: #f00 #0f0 #00f #f0f;
}
table th, table td{ /* Added padding for better layout after collapsing */
    padding: 4px 8px;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
               #
            </th>
            <th>
               Date
            </th>
        </tr> 
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                TUB1234
            </td>
            <td>
                2018/02/22
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I forgot to add styles for `td` and `th` which affected the problem. I've edited my question.

Comment: I suggest you to use rgba colors (rgb + alpha for opacity), I edited my answer to use it.

Comment: Is there any other way that I could cover cross section with black?

Comment: I edited my answer and added another snippet.  
I don't know about a method to pick which ones are above the others.

Answer (score 1):

it seems to me to be a bug,
my solution/ fix with angular/ material-version 12.0.2:

```js
 .full-size {
  width: 100%;

  thead {
    tr {
      td:first-child {
        padding-left: 24px;
        div:first-child {

        }
      }
      td {
        border-top: 1px solid #000000;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
        div {
          font-size: 0.95rem;
          font-weight: bolder;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  .checkbox {
    padding-left: 4px;
  }
}
```

```html
  <div>
    <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort class="mat-elevation-z8 full-size" #table>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="title">
        <td mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Title</td>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row;">{{row.title}}</td>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="created">
        <td mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Created</td>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row;">{{row.created | date:'d.MM.YYYY'}}</td>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="producer">
        <td mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Producer</td>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row;">{{row.producer}}</td>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="director">
        <td mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Director</td>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row;">{{row.director}}</td>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="isFavouritMovie">
        <td mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Your favourit?</td>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row;" class="checkbox">
          <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="row.isFavouritMovie">
          </mat-checkbox>
        </td>
      </ng-container>

      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
      <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>

      <!-- Row shown when there is no matching data. -->
      <tr class="mat-row" *matNoDataRow>
        <td class="mat-cell" colspan="4">No data matching the filter "{{input.value}}"</td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]"></mat-paginator>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's get funky...

`thead`, `tbody`, `tfoot` and `tr` don't really show their styling... (insert link to documentation explaining why).

In the meantime, you can change their `display` value to `block`, which will enable displaying styling (in your case, borders).

#### E.g.

```css
table, table * {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
}
th, td { 
  background: blue;
}
thead, tbody, tfoot {
  background: red;
}
tr {
  background: lime;
}
thead, tbody, tfoot, tr {
  display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead><tr><th>foo</th><th>foo</th></tr></thead>
  <tbody><tr><td>foo</td><td>foo</td></tr></tbody>
  <tfoot><tr><td>foo</td><td>foo</td></tr></tfoot>
</table>
```